# Silverlight 4 application freezes without throwing any exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria

I'm developing a Silverlight 4 RIA application. There is a `DataGrid` storing data and two buttons: add a new item and remove an item. After creating a new item for the **second** time the application freezes like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UQMUL1DbZPQ/TuCbRKE3dRI/AAAAAAAAAMU/X-RaZ_2nH5U/s1600/abc.jpg) - I'll explain the strange behaviour below.

The scenario of creating a new item looks like this:

1. After clicking, the child window appears. The reference to the domain data source used on the parrent page is being
   passed to the child window in the constructor.
2. The user chooses a file.
3. The file is send to a web service. In response the web service returns some data from that file.
4. A new data object is being created and inserted to domain data source.

The child window causes the entire application to freeze only when it's called twice, but the first call requires object creation. I can open and close the child window repeatedly and everything will work fine until a sequence of: open.create -> open.close / open.create occurs. I tried to trace all exceptions with VS tool (alt ctrl e) but there are none.

A breakpoint on

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
```

does not show anything either. Any ideas?

[Page code.](http://pastebin.com/RRSvbwiv)
[Child window code](http://pastebin.com/uEJvn6B2)

Comment: What does the WS stands for in step 3? I do not really understand on how you call the child window twice. Can you evaluate on that?

Comment: WS stands for Web Service. By calling child window twice I mean literally: Open a window(by clicking on a button), make an object(fill form), confirm (which also closes the window), then again click on the button and window opens. Application works until the child window is closed (no matter if another object was created or not).

Comment: Have you tried periodically pausing the application, checking the threads window? Tried adding some trace statements? Checking the task manager to see if CPU is being consumed? I glanced at the code and nothing jumps out, but it may help to know if it's frozen in the sense of waiting on something or if it seems to be spinning through something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following and everything will be fine.

```
    private void ChildWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = false;
    }
```

And to evaluate a bit more, ChildWindow_Closed is the outcome of setting the DialogResult at the first place. 
By re setting it unexpected things happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I was cracking my mind on that one. Removing this.DialogResult fixed the problem :) The strange thing is that when you add a new child window in VS2010 it automatically adds 2 events returning either true or false, so I fought its standard. That probably would be the last thing I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more research after you helped me with this issue. Seems its a SL4 bug.
This should also help. Topic about [this on SL forums.](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/176423.aspx/3/10)

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed(e);
        Application.Current.RootVisual.SetValue(Control.IsEnabledProperty, true);
    }
```